Is the kafka will maintain the replication factor, when the one of the replicated broker is down
I run a three broker in the cluster in my local machine, with ids (0, 1, 2)
I create a topic with one partition with replication factor 2
so, the replica is spread across the brokers
example the broker 1 and 2 contains the replicas
when I down the broker 2, is kafka will automatically migrate the replica from the broker 2 to broker 0? because my replication factor is 2
if yes, how it is done?
my case it is not happend, when I down the broker the topic description will still in same as like
replica : 1, 2, ISR : 1
is kafka rebalance the partitions automatically or we will trigger it manually

Automatic replication is not triggered when a broker is offline.
You could trigger it manually by using kafka-reassign-partitions, but then you'll have to manually clean the topic data from the offline broker if it comes back online

what happen when we run a 100s of brokers, and 20 brokers are down, is for this we manually trigger the rebalance with the long lines of json file? I thing this is a tedious operation,

There exists tools like CruiseControl to help with that
